# Screen Share stuck zoomed in

Tags: accessibility, back-to-my-mac

I have a Mac Mini hooked up to my television. On occasion I have to use my MacBook to screen share onto the Mini. Something happened where when screen sharing, the screen is zoomed in. It is NOT zoomed in when switching the TV input to use it as the monitor. It only happens when screen sharing.

How can I get this back to normal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Turn Scaling Off` from the `View` menu of `Screen Sharing`.